# How to use dto collection with spatie/data-transfer-object v3?

Tags: php, dto

I remember exactly that in previous versions the `Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObjectCollection` class was used for collections,

```
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObjectCollection;

abstract class Collection extends DataTransferObjectCollection
{

}
```

but in version 3 it is simply not there (maybe it was deleted). How can I use collections now?

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object#collections-of-dtos